# LVM commands produce no output

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7

I am trying to increase my boot partitions file size but I am having trouble. I do not know the volume's name and when I try the LVM commands to get more information I get no output. Does anyone know why?

```
/dev/sda1    300.00 MB  xfs  296.66 MB   2.78 MB  part/boot  
[root@centos7 ~]# lvs
[root@centos7 ~]# vgs
[root@centos7 ~]# vgdisplay
[root@centos7 ~]# lvdisplay
[root@centos7 ~]# pvdisplay
[root@centos7 ~]# pvs
[root@centos7 ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i lvm2
lvm2-2.02.177-4.el7.x86_64
lvm2-libs-2.02.177-4.el7.x86_64
[root@centos7 ~]# lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.177(2)-RHEL7 (2018-01-22)
  Library version: 1.02.146-RHEL7 (2018-01-22)
  Driver version:  4.37.0
```

output of mount command:

[root@centos7 ~]# mount

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=3980308k,nr_inodes=995077,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,memory)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda3 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13967)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/42 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=799236k,mode=700,uid=42,gid=42)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=799236k,mode=700)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/0/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Your installation was probably done without use of LVM. What is the output of 'mount' command?

Comment: @tonioc I have edited the post, take a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as you can see, your mount-points are directly to /dev/sda1, /dev/sda3 partition, which means no LVM was used for installation.

Now to increase your /boot:

1. do you really need it? Usually removing old kernels is enough. For this, consider using :

   sudo package-cleanup --oldkernels
2. If you still want/need to increase /boot, check with gparted if you still have available disk space. If so:

   - create a new partition (using gparted, this will probably create /dev/sda4)
   - create the xfs on it (mkfs.xfs)
   - mount it to /mnt/tmp for example
   - copy files from /boot to /mnt/tmp
   - update /etc/fstab to mount new partition

If you have no more free disk available, you'll have to reduce / partition. If think this will need to be done from a live CD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your first solution helped, thank you so much. I appreciate your second solution,  I will try it just to learn something new.